# How can I configure yarn cluster for parallel execution of Applications?

Tags: bigdata, cluster-computing, admin, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

When I run spark job on yarn cluster, Applications are running in queue. So how can I run in parallel number of Applications?.

Comment: What have you tried already? For users to help you it is best to provide specific examples of where you are failing with your code or application. Can you provide some more detailed information?

Comment: Thanks for ur rply, Generally when I submit spark or mapreduce program to the yarn cluster applications are running perfectly without error. But applications are running in series that means one after another. I want to run applications simultaneously for that additionally what configuration i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your YARN scheduler option is set to FIFO. Please change it to FAIR or capacity scheduler.Fair Scheduler attempts to allocate resources so that all running applications get the same share of resources.

> The Capacity Scheduler allows sharing of a Hadoop cluster along
>   organizational lines, whereby each organization is allocated a certain
>   capacity of the overall cluster. Each organization is set up with a
>   dedicated queue that is configured to use a given fraction of the
>   cluster capacity. Queues may be further divided in hierarchical
>   fashion, allowing each organization to share its cluster allowance
>   between different groups of users within the organization. Within a
>   queue, applications are scheduled using FIFO scheduling.

If you are using capacity scheduler then 
In spark submit mention your queue --queue queueName

Please try to change this capacity scheduler property

yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications = any number

it will decide how many application will run parallely

Comment: Dynamic resource allocation via Yarn? Too many issues with shuffles and executor relinquishing?

Comment: @thebluephantom didn’t get the issues you mentioned. Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spark will acquire all available resources when it launches a job.

You can limit the amount of resources consumed for each job via the spark-submit command.

Add the option "--conf spark.cores.max=1" to spark-submit. You can change the number of cores to suite your environment. For example if you have 100 total cores, you might limit a single job to 25 cores or 5 cores, etc.

You can also limit the amount of memory consumed: --conf spark.executor.memory=4g

You can change settings via spark-submit or in the file conf/spark-defaults.conf. Here is a link with documentation:

[Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: That implies the question is a supposition where sequentual scheduling is concerned. Also, what about YARN Dynamc Resource Allocation? @John Hanley

Comment: @thebluephantom - If you have a better answer jump in and post one.

Comment: I suspect you know better, so just complementing.

Comment: Hi John, I have 2machines with 32gb ram and 8 core each machine, So can u help me how to configure yarn with spark setting and how to tune the resources. I'm using zeppelin interface for submitting the spark jobs to cluster.

Comment: @vikramreddy. Create a new question with more details. I will be happy to help if I can.

Comment: @John Hanley here is the question help me. "How to configure the Yarn cluster with spark?"